# OSPF areas with two ABRs

Tags: ospf

With the following hypothetical network (each link between routers is /31 and configured as OSPF point to point)

[image]

Do R1 and R2 need to be neighbors inside area 1 considering their interfaces are all in different subnets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've drawn the network, R1 and R2 don't need to be neighbors in either area.  The only reason they *might* need to be neighbors is for redundancy in case one ASBR fails.  But since the routers in area 1 are connected to both ASBRs, this isn't a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if there was a special case for two ASBRs